# How to use urllib2 when users only have a API token?

Tags: python, urllib2

how would i tranfoms this curl command:

```
curl -v -u 82xxxxxxxxxxxx63e6:api_token -X GET https://www.toggl.com/api/v6/time_entries.json
```

into urlib2?

I found this tutorial: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml

but they use a password and username. I can only use an API token.

Thank you.

see also this question:

[Urllib2 raises 403 error while the same request in curl works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062433/urllib2-raises-403-error-while-the-same-request-in-curl-works-fine)

Comment: it's the same thing. the api token is used as a password in the CURL example you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urllib2 is known to suck big time when it comes to authentication. To save some kitten lifes you should use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html